# Patching/Extending route UrlGenerator for url rewriting to replace all spaces with hypens

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting, routes, extend, slug

I have routes like this:

```
user:
    path: /u/{id}/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeMyBundle:User:user, name: '' }
    requirements:
        id: '[0-9]+'
```

{name} is there just to have a nice looking url for users and SEO. I don't use {name} for anything in my application because {id} does the job.
{name} usually consists of multiple words (first + last name etc) and generated urls look like this:

http://my.project/u/12/Firstname%20LastName

I generate url either in twig template with path('user', {id: user_id, name: user_name}) or in php with with $this->get('router')->generate(...)

I would like to avoid having %20 and replacing all spaces with hyphens to have links look like this:

http://my.project/u/12/Firstname-LastName

It looks more readable and I read somewhere that google like hyphens more...

The best way would be if route generator would do that. Just replace alle spaces with hyphens. I don't need anything else at the moment and it cannot affect anything because it {name} or some other descriptive params are just used for SEO and they are not used in application. {id} is important param

I was not able to find a way to do it nice by some parameter so I just opened **vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php** and added "%20" and a space to **decodedChars**:

```
protected $decodedChars = array(
    # ...
    '%2A' => '*',
    '%7C' => '|',
    # replace spaces with hyphen
    '%20' => '-',
    ' '   => '-' 
);
```

It is working but I don't feel well with this solution because I am patching symfony's core.
And later on I would maybe like to lowercase {name} or some other params per default.

Is there are some better way for this? I would feel that the best way for adminstrating such stuff would be if it would possible to define some "postSlugify" params in routing.yml...

I could make function getName() and getNameSluggified() in my User entity and something similar in other entities but there should be a way to automate this without creating n number of similar functions in every entity.

Comment: You should consider using [Doctrine Sluggable extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md) ;)

Comment: @Kanalkyte ;). thanks, it works pretty nice. what I don't like is that it forces me to make "slug" column in the entity. no possibility to create slug live. and if i later on add one more column to slug, slug will stay same. am i correct?

Comment: Slugs can be made out of several columns :) So you can refresh slugs (simply use `findAll()`, and `persist()` + `flush()` to refresh all slugs in one shot !) I did a little command script to do that for me. Don't know if there is any easier way to do so :/

Comment: i was thinking about that but slug does not change as long as the value of the column did not change. i had to run persist/flush twice, 1st time to overwrite column, 2nd time to set the real value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it worked for you, here's the complete answer :

You can use [Doctrine Sluggable extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md) :

```
 class Foo
 {
     // your attributes
     // in the folowing "fields", you cas use several fields
    /**
    * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name", "bar"})
    * @ODM\String
    */
     private $slug;

  // some stuff
}
```

If you change your *field* attribute, you will need to refresh your slugs. [Here is the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791738/regenerating-slug-doctrine2) I found about refreshing slugs.

You can implement this in a command-line tool by using [this documentation page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html).